# iOS 7.1 tableView reloadData not updating tableView correctly

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios7.1

Something strange is happening for me with `reloadData` ONLY IN iOS 7.1. This code works PERFECTLY in iOS 7.0. I update some variables and then call `reloadData`:

```
myNum = 12;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    … 
    [cell.leftScoreButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myNum] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.leftScoreButton.enabled = NO;
    …
```

This is no longer updating the button title correctly in 7.1, but it works fine in 7.0. Also if I pop up with an AlertDialog, then it will successfully reload the `tableView` button with the correct title. What part of `AlertDialog` calls update/refresh the underlying screen? Can I call that manually without actually popping up with an `AlertDialog`?

I have already tried calling `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]` and `setNeedsLayout`. Neither helped.

Comment: I've also noticed several iOS 7.1 only UI bugs, it seems like it's more of a step backwards than forwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After playing around for a while I noticed it is related to the buttons being enabled. For the row that wasn't updating properly I had the buttons disabled. I just added

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    … 
    [cell.leftScoreButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myNum] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    cell.leftScoreButton.enabled = YES;
    cell.leftScoreButton.enabled = NO;
    …
```

so I enable and then immediately disable, and now they update properly.

Comment: Have same issue: button titles won't update in table view. This workaround helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Resolve by setting same title for `UIControlStateNormal`, `UIControlStateSelected` and  `UIControlStateHighlighted`.

Looks more clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this code did the work for me:

```
[cell.buttonName setNeedsLayout];
```

I asked the button to be layout again.